# How to remove attribute of container in layout XML

Tags: magento2, layout

Let's say I want to remove the `page-wrapper` css class from the `page.wrapper` container. How would I do that? I know that I can add additional attributes or change existing attributes this way in the `default.xml` of my theme or module:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper" htmlId="wrapper" htmlClass="foo" />
```

Just using `htmlClass=""` does not work. Magento will complain that this is an invalid value.

Comment: Why would it need to be empty? What about a class-name that is known *not* to be used? `htmlClass="certainlynotfoo"` - Not trying to sound malicious but no need for it to be removed, if it can just be changed =)

Comment: Sure, it can be changed to anything. But I would still want to know if and how existing attributes can be removed.

Comment: I do apologise, I confess I skimmed over the first paragraph :X Having done a little research on this since (I don't know the answer to your question, much to the labyrinth that is Magento); There doesn't seem to have a native method to do this it seems. It would be OTT to `remove=..` the tag entirely & include it back in without the `htmlClass` too.